# How to transform data from MongoDB to fit in ngrx entityCache?

Tags: angular, ngrx

How would I go about transforming data from MongoDB so that it fits the ngrx data entityCache? 
Right now, the data is there, but the formatting is off as the objects nested in the entities property are undefined.

group-data.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultDataService, HttpUrlGenerator, QueryParams } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Group } from 'src/app/models/group.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface GroupData {
    count: number;
    groups: Group[];
}

@Injectable()
export class GroupDataService extends DefaultDataService<Group> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrl: HttpUrlGenerator) {
        super('Group', http, httpUrl);
    }
    getWithQuery(params: QueryParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<GroupData>('http://localhost:3000/api/groups?' + params)
            .pipe(
                tap(data => console.log(data)),
                map(data => data.groups)
            );
    }
}
```

the resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, filter, first, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { GroupEntityService } from './group-entity.service';


@Injectable()
export class GroupResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {

    constructor(private groupService: GroupEntityService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        const topic = route.queryParams.topic;
        return this.groupService.loaded$
            .pipe(
                tap(loaded => {
                    if (!loaded) {
                        this.groupService.getWithQuery(`topic=${topic.toLowerCase()}&PageSize=2&currentPage=1`);
                    }
                }),
                filter(loaded => !!loaded),
                first()
            );
    }
}
```

group-entity.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityCollectionServiceBase, EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Group } from 'src/app/models/group.model';


@Injectable()
export class GroupEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Group> {
    constructor(serviceElFac: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
        super('Group', serviceElFac);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use EntityAdapter ??

Comment: I'm using ngrx data

Comment: I know, show me your state.ts

Comment: why would anyone downvote this question?

Comment: hummm.. Basically you must have a field "reducer.ts" and "state.ts", I have to see what you have inside

Comment: you mean a reducer.ts file?

Comment: Yes sorry for my english

Comment: no worries, i thought that's what you meant. I don't have any reducer, action, or effect. No need with ngrx data, that's why it's pretty useful and saves a lot of code for CRUD operations. My issue is that the EntityCache expects data in a certain format, which isn't what you get back from MongoDB (and I find it weird considering MongoDB works really well with angular. I'm simply trying to transform the data I get back from the server, but I'm struggling to create a custom EntityReducer for a articular entity (group in this instance). The doc isn't helpful at all...

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, no need to customise the reducer for the entity in question. I just had to overwrite the _id property with id instead in the data.service where I tweaked the getWithQuery method, as well as reformatting the data slightly.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DefaultDataService, HttpUrlGenerator, QueryParams } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Group } from 'src/app/models/group.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class GroupDataService extends DefaultDataService<Group> {
    constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrl: HttpUrlGenerator) {
        super('Group', http, httpUrl);
    }
    getWithQuery(params: QueryParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<Group[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/groups?' + params)
            .pipe(
                map(data => {
                    const obj = {};
                    data.map(g => {
                        obj[g._id] = {
                            id: g._id,
                            name: g.name,
                            swearingAllowed: g.swearingAllowed,
                            creator: g.admin,
                            topic: g.topic
                        }
                    });
                    return Object.values(obj);
                })
            );
    }
};
```